# A non-Hermitian system whose "Hamiltonian" is the annihilation operator

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, hamiltonian

Consider a notional quantum system whose "Hamiltonian" is the annihilation operator,
                    $$H=a .$$
Its initial state $|ψ(0)\rangle$ is
  $$|\psi(0)\rangle=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} c_{n}| n\rangle,$$
so
$$|\psi(t)\rangle=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\bigg[\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(t/i \hbar)^{k}}{k !} c_{k+n} \sqrt{(n+k) \cdots(n+1)}\bigg]| n\rangle$$
($|n\rangle$ is the eigenstates of the operator $P^2/2m+1/2 mω^2 X^2$).

Now, if we normalize this state, is this state possible to tend to a stable state?

I already have two answers with special limitiations to initial state:

1. If $|ψ(0)\rangle$ is an eigenstate of the annihilation operator $a$,
   $$|ψ(0)\rangle=|α\rangle,\qquad (a|α\rangle=α|α\rangle),$$
   then
   $$|ψ(t)\rangle=|α\rangle .$$
2. If $|ψ(0)\rangle$ is
   $$|\psi(0)\rangle=\sum_{n=0}^{N} c_{n}| n\rangle ,$$
   then
   $$|\psi(t)\rangle=\sum_{n=0}^{N}\bigg[\sum_{k=0}^{N-n} \frac{(t/i \hbar)^{k}}{k !} c_{k+n} \sqrt{(n+k) \cdots(n+1)}\bigg]| n\rangle.$$
   We then have
   $$\lim _{t \rightarrow+\infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{\langle\psi(t) | \psi(t)\rangle}}|\psi(t)\rangle=| 0\rangle. $$

Are there other special cases? Or is there a general answer?  Any ideas  may help me a lot.

Comment: Normally the ("stationary") eigenstates of a (nonhermitean) operator serve to find the time dependent solution of the corresponding TDSE, but suitable multiplication by phases $e^{-it\alpha}$, each. *Why* would you use a basis of eigenstates of another (hermitian) operator? Have you looked at the propagator $\int d^2\alpha ~~ |\alpha\rangle e^{-it\alpha} \langle \alpha |$?

Comment: The Hamiltonian cannot be the annihilation operator. The Hamiltonian has to be a hermitian (self-adjoint) operator because it is linked to the observable quantity energy (eigenvectors of $H$ have a definite value of energy). The annihilation operator is not hermitian because its adjoint is the creation operator, in fact $a$ is almost *anti-hermitian* (up to multiplication by a constant, $a^{\dagger}$ is the inverse operator of $a$). The operator that **can** be a Hamiltonian is $a^{\dagger}a$, which as you can verify is hermitian (it's the number operator, it gives you the number of quanta).

Comment: @SV  Hamiltonians may, of course, be non-hermitean, but of those only PT_symmetric ones make sense. But it appears the OP is just looking at a PDE, a lark. Calling his operator a Hamiltonian is just a name, evoking notation, not a statement of further physical significance. Is calling it Blamiltonian better?

Comment: @CosmasZachos I don't know about QFT, but at least in classical QM I thought only hermitian operators made sense for observables (please correct me if I'm wrong). Again I know the story could be quite different for relativistic QM but as far as I can tell the question doesn't mention that possibility. Blamiltonian would be a perfect name.

Comment: @SV. Blamiltonian let it be, then. *Nobody* is yapping about observables. I believe the OP is addressing a formal group motion, and rides on our formal intuition associated to the hamiltonian, or perhaps his. He is, I hope we all agree, running through a family of coherent states.

Comment: Well I found at least one error in the question. If $\Psi(0)$ is an eigenvector of $a$ with eigenvalue $\alpha$, and $a$ is the Blamiltonian, then $\Psi(t)=\mathrm{exp}[(-it/\hbar)a]\Psi(0)=\mathrm{exp}(-it\alpha/\hbar)\Psi(0)$. Eigenstates of the Hamiltonian get a phase in their time evolution, the OP omitted that.

Comment: @SV. Of course. That's the point I make in my answer. I set $\hbar=1$ in natural units, naturally.

Comment: I love your casual use of puns, but I'd better not chat around here because the comments are not intended for that.

Answer (score 1):

Normally the ("stationary") eigenstates of an operator (here, your nonhermitean hamiltonian) serve to find the time-dependent solution of the corresponding TDSE, by suitable multiplication by phases $e^{−itα}$, each.

Why would you use a basis of eigenstates of another (hermitean oscillator *H*) operator? 
The coherent states $|\alpha\rangle$  you are considering are an [overcomplete set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coherent_state#Mathematical_features_of_the_canonical_coherent_states), so use *them* as your basis,
$$
|\psi(0)\rangle=\int d^2 \alpha  ~ c(\alpha) |\alpha\rangle \\ \mapsto |\psi(t)\rangle=\int d^2\alpha ~  c(\alpha) e^{-it\alpha} |\alpha\rangle,    
$$

Have you looked at the propagator $\int d^2 α ~  |α\rangle e^{−itα}\langle α|~~$   ?  Contrast to the [displacement operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Displacement_operator).

It is then manifest that your first answer is not quite right, 
$$
|\psi(t)\rangle = e^{-it\alpha} |\alpha\rangle,
$$
unless you explicitly declare you are uninterested in the phase; and is only a fixed point for $\alpha =0$, namely your second answer: the vacuum is time-invariant.